# Visualizing probability distribution Spotfire

Tags: visualization, spotfire

For every row I have a probability distribution over language topics. It looks like this:

```
comment | topic 1 | topic 2 | topic 3 
bla bla | 0.8     | 0.1     | 0.1     
bli bli | 0.2     | 0.7     | 0.1     
blo blo | 0.1     | 0.2     | 0.7
```

I want to show the average probabilities over the current filter in a bar plot, so that I can zoom into specific comments or combinations of comments, with a topic per bar. How can I use different variables for different bars in Spotfire?

EDIT: Here is a loose paint example with 3 topics:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/E2Dz0dC.png]

Comment: Can you elaborate on using different variables in the chart? You can use a property control as a variable but I'm not sure that's what you are trying to do. Perhaps you want to make a details visualization? That is when you click on any bar in your bar chart, a new chart will show only data from that selection. Is this more like what you want to do?

Comment: More like the second thing, I made a small paint example to show what I want

Answer (score 1):

So there are two, or more approaches you can do with this. The simplest is to, on your bar chart that shows everything:

Right Click > Create Details Visualization > Select the visualization you want.

Now, clicking on any single or combination of bars in your "main" bar chart will render data in your details visualization, based off this data. You can manage what marking limit what visualizations by Right Click > Properties > Data tab and set the marking and Limit data using markings.

Another, less clean approach, is to limit the data custom expression. In the Properties > Data Tab, at the bottom you will see "Limit data using expression" Here you can filter out any data with any custom expression you want. It's true power comes in when you use property controls, like variables. Here is an example.

1. Insert > New Text Area
2. Right Click on Text Area > Edit Text Area
3. On the Text Area tool Bar > Insert Property Control > (pick your type)

Then set your property control up like you want. There are many options and the details on the different ways, properties, etc is too lengthy for this question.

Now, this property control works like a variable, you can reference it. Here is an example. In "Limit data using custom expression" that I mentioned above, use it in a custom expression like `If([SomeColumn] = "${yourPropertyControlName}",TRUE,FALE)`

---

### EDIT

Thanks for the comment. Based on your data above, you'll need to add a details visualization as stated above, then complete these steps

1. Right Click > Properties > Value Axis > then add one for each column
2. Avg([topic 1]), Avg([topic 2]), etc
3. Category Axis > set this to (Column Names)

Otherwise, you will need to transform your data via Insert ? Transformations > and you will need to pivot / unpivot your data accordingly.

Comment: My native language is not English so I'm maybe misunderstanding you, but what I want is to click rows in a Table and show the results in the bar char. Every bar in the bar chart refers to a different column, that is what I have issues with, the last part